# Is it possible to share System.Runtime.Caching cached objects between multiple web servers?

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching, distributed-caching

This question:

[Is it possible to share HttpRuntime.Cache between multiple web servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144410/is-it-possible-to-share-httpruntime-cache-between-multiple-web-servers)

..Relates to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aspx

..I think I know the answer, but for everyone's benefit, with the newer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx

It is realistically possible? Or would one be better off using memcached / AppFabric / redis / xyz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HttpRuntime.Cache runs in-process (i.e., in server memory) and cannot be shared between multiple web servers. You can extend the mentioned System.Runtime.Caching with a custom provider to centralize caching using  a platform such as SQL Server or a dedicated server.

Recommended multi-web server caching strategy would definitely depend on the environment.

On the lower end of scale, using SQL Server is a quick option that is probably familiar to a .NET developer.  Another option is using a web service (e.g., WCF) to centralize cached data calls.

On the higher end, you have mentioned the leaders in the field: memcached, AppFabric, Redis, etc. If these are already setup in your environment and/or you are familiar with them I could definitely see using them whenever you have multiple web servers (big or small).

I recommend at least checking out Redis.  It's the newer category of the group mentioned but it's lightweight, fast and in addition to the key/value store it has other functionality great for distributed systems such as pub/sub.

Comment: Cool, I expected it could not be done just wanted it stated here.  I guess by 'in-memory' you mean really mean 'in-process' because memcached, AppFabric, Redis are all in memory too of course.  What I was wondering was if HttpRuntime.Cache had some easy separate-process mode like ASP.NET session state does

Comment: ...I guess you could always 'roll your own' separate process using it...but why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, in-process is a more appropriate term (I'll edit).  FYI, Redis does operate by default with persistent storage... you can however switch it to run strictly in memory.  Still very fast with persistence and a nice to have feature as compared to competitors.

Comment: If you're in a .net (Microsoft) environment, I would highly recommend opting for AppFabric, since it leverages existing knowledge about 2008 R2 and other supporting infrastructures.

Answer (score 0):

.Net's System.Runtime.Caching api provides abstract class [ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx) that provides the base methods and properties for accessing the object cache. Only implementation of this abstract class provided in .Net is [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) which is an in-proc cache and cannot be shared between multiple web servers

However you can yourself extend ObjectCache class to incorporate functionality of a distributed cache.

Or for an out of the box solution you can use a distributed caching solution that provides ObjectCache's implementation for distributed caching.
[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) is one of the distributed caching solutions that provide's ObjectCache implementation, as described [here](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/dot-net-support.html)

> NCache has developed a provider for .NET 4.0 Cache that results in an extremely fast and highly scalable .NET distributed cache. This allows applications using .NET 4.0 Cache to now scale to multi-server environments and also remove any database bottlenecks.
>   You can incorporate NCache as your .NET distributed cache without any code changes to your application. You only change your configuration file to use NCache.